# Download Nuget Package using Nuget.exe

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Im working on an automation solution for transfering nuget packages from nuget.org to a private nuget feed. Is it possible to download nuget packages using nuget.exe? If i run the following command, it fails because it tries to install it to the directory, but i dont need to install the package i just need to download it.

```
.\nuget.exe install Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 -source nuget.org -force
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error NU5000: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 7.0.1' has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project 'C:\foo'.
```

I am looking for something like a -force option, so that i can just download the package without installing it.

Answer (score -1):

I Have the same problem! It seems like the nuget.exe have some hints of whats the target:
Error NU5000: Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 7.0.14' has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project 'c:\Nuget'.

It seems like there is no agnostic way of taking the nuget home and nothing else.

Comment: This doesn't really look like an answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35543914)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).